# What is the source of formal descriptions for large uncomputable ordinals clockable by Infinite Time Turing Machines?

Tags: logic, automata, ordinals, turing-machines

I can imagine the process of analyzing the computation of an ITTM at any limit stage denoted by $\alpha$ if $\alpha$ is a computable ordinal: basically, we take the description of some standard Turing machine $M_i$ and use the wellorder that it encodes. Then we analyze the computational process of an ITTM using the ordinal that corresponds to $M_i$.

But if we want to analyze the computational process when $\alpha$ is uncomputable (assuming that Infinite Time Turing Machines can clock very large uncomputable ordinals), we need to obtain a **precise description** of $\alpha$ somewhere. But where can we find formal descriptions of such ordinals in the first place (assuming that the set of these descriptions is required to be countable)?

**EDIT**
This question can be formulated as follows.

Imagine the existence of an oracle that always tells the truth. Assuming that you and the oracle solve problems of

> given a natural number $x$, find an ITTM that is indexed by $x$

and

> given a real number $x$, decode it as an ordinal

in exactly the same way, this oracle sends the following message:

> I have chosen a natural number $N$. All I can tell you is that an ITTM indexed by $N$ clocks some ordinal $\alpha$. You can send me any real number that encodes any ordinal, and I will immediately tell you whether this ordinal is equal to $\alpha$ or not. You have an infinite amount of infinitely powerful computational resources and infinite amount of time. Moreover, if you send me any **countable** set $S$ of ordinals, I will send you a number $0$ if this set does not contain $\alpha$; otherwise, I will send you a positive number $i$ such that an $i$-th element of $S$ is equal to $\alpha$. And here are three rules that must be taken into account: (i) any set $S$ that you send me is required to be a set of real numbers, where each element encodes an ordinal in a particular (fixed) way. It is your choice to fix such encoding, but you must tell me about your choice so that we can interpret all reals in the same way; (ii) If you send me a countable set (described in the previous rule), then (assuming that we agree on a fixed algorithm that decodes a single real number into a countable set of real numbers) you are required to provide an exact description of an algorithm (namely, an index of an ITTM together with a real number that encodes an ordinal for a stage when the output tape is expected to contain the real number that encodes the entire set $S$) that generates $S$; (iii) for any ITTM indexed by any natural number $n$, you are allowed to ask for a real number that appears on the output tape at stage $\beta$, but if and only if you provide a real number that encodes an ordinal $\beta$ (in the same fixed way that you have chosen). You can store these numbers in arbitrary (finite/infinite) sets/multisets and operate with them in any way you want.
>   So, if you find $\alpha$, you win.

Question: does there exist a way to always win, no matter which $N$ the oracle chooses? If yes, then how?

Comment: Just to clarify, you're essentially asking how we make sense of "the ITTM's situation (= what's on the tape, where the machine head is, and what state the machine's in) at stage $\lambda$ on input $A$" when $\lambda$ is a non-computable limit ordinal - is this correct?

Comment: @NoahSchweber: not exactly. The question is how to obtain a precise description (in the form of a real number) of a non-computable ordinal $\lambda$ in the first place. I edited the question to add a clarification.

Comment: @lyricallywicked Your description in edit is a bit hard for me to follow. But when you wrote: *"how to obtain a precise description (in the form of a real number) of a non-computable ordinal $\lambda$ in the first place."*  I described how to obtain the "description"(as a real) of $\omega_{CK}$ (which isn't computable) in my answer for example. But I am not fully clear on what the question is though. Maybe your question is more general or something like that etc. ..... for which I gave the link below the answer ..... which is quite advanced for me tbh.

Comment: Actually, even though I don't understand what you wrote in edit, I have a guess regarding the intent of your question. I will modify my answer later on accordingly (based on what I think you are asking).

Comment: @NoahSchweber That would be a very good question I think (with some philosophical undertones). For example, in one of the questions I asked months ago $J_2$ was mentioned (link:https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0509245.pdf). I don't understand what $J_2$ is, but it seems to be a very large value (based on strong closure properties apparently). So when powerful enough programs go beyond this, I have to admit I don't really understand what that would *really* "mean". But I suppose I am musing too much without knowing what I am talking about, so I will stop.

Comment: The closure functions used to define $J_\alpha$ aren't extremely strong, all members of $J_2$ have rank $<\omega 2$, and $J_2$ does not have a "thick" powerset either, as $J_2\cap V_{\omega+1}=L_{\omega+1}$. (Both from [Devlin74](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/30905237.pdf).) It reminds me of Harvey Friedman's proposal to carry out as much math as possible in the cumulative hierarchy's $V_6$ ([Friedman21](https://bpb-us-w2.wpmucdn.com/u.osu.edu/dist/1/1952/files/2021/05/TangIncLect1-050721.pdf))

Answer (score 1):

It's a good question. I will describe those specific aspects of the answer which I know about (but it will be a bit long though). There are very many aspects of course, of which I don't know much about.

Specifically though, I don't know much of anything about how models like $\omega$ tape ITTMs handle this (that's why I will not try to describe how they handle this issue). So I will assume a more general model (such as ORM or extended tape ITTM).

---

First of all, one basic principle you can observe is that if you have access to well-order relation $lessequals:\mathbb{N}^2 \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ (for a well-order of $\mathbb{N}$) of order-type $\alpha$ then you can use it to halt a "little above" $\alpha$. More specifically, given the access to the function $lessequals$, there will be some $\beta \geq \alpha$ such that our given program halt at time $\beta$. This isn't difficult (but not obvious at first though).

Before stating the process, let me first mention that all the steps below that have been described informally can indeed be checked by a powerful enough program model. First let $address:\alpha \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ be the (unique) order-preserving bijection(under the well-ordering relation) from $\alpha$ to $\mathbb{N}$. *[I am not fully sure whether that's the best way to put it formally ... someone can correct this if I am wrong]*. Now we define $address_{p}:p \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ (where $p \leq \alpha$) to denote the restriction of the address function.

Now suppose that you are given an entirely arbitrary function $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \{0,1\}$. Note that we don't even have to know before-hand whether $f$ is a well-order relation (for *some* well-order of $\mathbb{N}$). The thing is that we can do both of the following at once: **(1)** We can check whether $f$ codes a well-order or not. **(2)** If the answer to (1) is yes, then suppose $f$ codes a well-order of order-type $\alpha$. Then our program will halt just above $\alpha$.

The first thing that we check is whether $f$ linear order on $\mathbb{N}$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order). One can observe here is that in a program-like model you can just check each individual property in about $\omega$ time (and hence all three of them in about $\omega \cdot 3$ time).

After this the main idea is to form the function $address_p:p \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ in stages, until the stage $\alpha$. First let's denote $range(address_p)=A_p$ and $B_p=\mathbb{N}-A_p$ for the sake of convenience/brevity. Initially we have $A_0=\phi$. Our first question is: what's the value $address(0)$? We basically check all the elements in $x \in B_0$ one by one. We want to check whether $f(x,y)$ is true for all elements $y \in B_0(=\mathbb{N})$ and furthermore check whether $f(x,z)$ is false for all elements $z \in A_0(=\phi)$.

Now there are two different things that could happen. **(i)** We can't find any $x \in A_0$ which satisfies the above requirement. **(ii)** We can find an $x \in A_0$ which satisfies the above requirement. If (i) happens to be true, then the program can simply return *"the given $f$ doesn't code a well-order"*. If you observe a bit closely the truth of (i) implies an infinite descending chain. Now if (ii) happens to be true, then the element $a \in B_0$ for which this was true we basically set $address(0)=a$ (re-call that we are building this function in stages) and $A_1=A_0 \cup a$. You might object what happens if we get two different $a,b \in B_0$(where $a\neq b$) so that both satisfy the given condition (but this won't happen because of the condition of linear order satisfied by $f$).

Essentially the above template is what you follow through out the calculation. We have a counter variable $p$ which starts from $0$ and which we keep increasing. At any given stage we have already formed $address_{p}:p \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$, and hence also the sets $A_p$ and $B_p$. But the question is that when do we know when to stop?? The answer is simple, once we think about it a bit! We have to keep a check on the set $B_p$ at each value $p$. Once $B_p=\phi$ we have actually formed the function $address:\alpha \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$. In that case we stop after we observe this condition.

Note that we could also stop well before $B_p=\phi$. But actually, this would ONLY happen if $f$ didn't code a well-order. If $f$ did code a well-order we would stop at some point $\beta$ where $\beta \geq \alpha$.

Finally, let me add a bit of explanation how, in a formal sense, this construction proceeds. In a formal sense, the idea is that since we have already shown $f$ to be a linear order on $\mathbb{N}$, now we need to prove the lack of infinite descending sequences. And this is the main idea with the construction of the set $A_p$ in stages. In particular, for any arbitrary stage $p \leq \alpha$, if the program doesn't stop/halt at that stage then we can say: *"There are no infinite descending sequences which use an element that belongs to $A_p$"*. In other words, for every infinite descending sequence $g:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ [that is a function $g$ such that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $g(n) \neq g(n+1)$ and $f(g(n+1),g(n))=1$], we must have $range(g) \cap A_p = \phi$. We could go along and try to show this by (transfinite) induction I think.

---

Note that directly using construction above we can basically clock just above $\omega_{CK}$. Since our model already has access to all partial recursive functions (of two variables), we first check which of these functions are total. So we basically have a set $C \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ which initially contains indexes for all programs which compute a function from $\mathbb{N}^2$ to $\{0,1\}$. One by one we start picking an element $x \in C$ and then try to check whether it codes a well-order or not. In either case, after we have checked that we remove that element $x$ from $C$. In this case again our main stopping/halting condition is to check $C=\phi$. Some reflection will show that, in this manner, we will halt just above $\omega_{CK}$. (I think one can also use an alternative method like I mentioned in one of my older questions [Halting at Exact Time](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2412559/halting-at-exact-time))

I think there could be another method in a sense. I am not really familiar with it, so I am not comfortable mentioning it in detail. Given what is mentioned in [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/314377/natural-examples-of-recursive-pseudowellorderings) question, one could just use the corresponding (recursive) ordering relation (right from the start of a program) to stop just beyond $\omega_{CK}$. But I am simply not familiar with it so I would just stop at that.

---

Now coming to your main question, how do we clock above $\omega^{CK}_{2}$ for example. You can basically store all pairs of the form $(x,y)$ (where $x\in \mathbb{N}$ and $y \in \omega_{CK}$) where $x$ is an index of a program coding a well-order and $y$ is the order-type of the corresponding well-order. This can just be done by using the first construction described in the answer.

Alternatively, you can also store all $(x,y)$ where $x \in \mathcal{O}$ and $y=|x|_\mathcal{O}$. But the construction will be a bit different (basically similar to what I described in my question above).

It is obvious that we can use any of the above collections to form a well-order of $\mathbb{N}$ with order-type $\omega_{CK}$. But now our infinite program can easily form a collection of all ordinary programs with access to the well-order relation for $\omega_{CK}$. And much in the same way as before, this can be used to stop above $\omega^{CK}_{2}$ for example.

---

My knowledge is a quite limited so I don't know/understand the full extent. Though this can vary depending on specific model you use. You would usually find it in relevant papers though, I think.

---

**EDIT:**

As far as I can guess, what you are asking is that if $\alpha$ is a clockable ordinal, then can find a function $f:\mathbb{N}^2 \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ that can serve as a well-order relation for well-order of $\mathbb{N}$ with order-type $\alpha$. Once again I will assume a program style model (with variables with free range) .... mostly only because of familiarity reason.

Suppose some program starting from empty state halts at stage $\alpha+1$. And now we want to write the "description" of $\alpha$ as a real. First we set a variable equal to $\alpha$ (which we can do easily). Then we simulate all programs (not ordinary ones, the ones from our general model) from empty input (using dovetailing etc.). Observe that this kind of simulation is indeed possible. Initially set $C=\mathbb{N}$. When a given program reaches stage $\alpha$ without halting it is excluded/removed from the simulation (and hence from $C$). When a program with index $x \in \mathbb{N}$ halts at time $t<\alpha$ we add the pair $(x,t)$ in some main list $L$ (and also remove $x$ from $C$).

The above routing halts when $C=\phi$. Indeed the routine will halt at some point (though it needs a bit of pondering), most importantly because we don't allow any program to run for more than $\alpha$ time. And once you look carefully enough, the list $L$ can be used to describe the real which codes $\alpha$. For example, if $L$ included for some $\beta<\alpha$, three different elements $(10,\beta)$,$(14,\beta)$,$(18,\beta)$ then we just keep $(10,\beta)$. Hence we have the well-order relation for well-order of a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ with order-type $\alpha$. This can easily be converted to obtain the relation for a well-order of $\mathbb{N}$.

To make sure that the above construction works we need to prove that whenever the code $f:\mathbb{N}^2 \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ for a well-order of order-type $\alpha$ is writeable, then so is code $g:\mathbb{N}^2 \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ for a well-order of *any* order-type $\beta<\alpha$. For this, consider the program that starts from empty input and gives us $f$. Now even an ordinary program can be used to obtain $g$.

Comment: For the comment towards the end of answer, perhaps this link might be good as a reference (advanced but probably good for the long term): https://mathoverflow.net/questions/159907.

Comment: Also, there might be an added redundancy or two in the first construction I think.

Comment: I can imagine generating _relatively small_ uncomputable ordinals, but I am not sure how this will work for very large recursively inaccessible ordinals... Note that if any ordinal is clockable, we must obtain its formal description somehow; otherwise, we cannot even refer to a stage that corresponds to the ordinal.

Comment: @lyricallywicked It might depend on what you mean by "relatively small" though. You can use a similar method to what I described to reach  $\omega^{CK}_{\omega}$ or $\omega^{CK}_{\omega^1_{CK}}$ for example.

Comment: At any rate, it seems that what you are asking is: *"if $\alpha$ is clockable then can we obtain the description of $\alpha$ as a real."* The answer is yes. I will edit soon.

Comment: > First we set a variable equal to $\alpha$ (which we can do easily) < We cannot do this if we don't have a real number that encodes a limit ordinal $\alpha$. But where can we obtain such numbers for very large (recursively inaccessible) uncomputable ordinals? And those two ordinals that you have mentioned in the comment above are very small in comparison with clockable ordinals.

Comment: If the method described in the answer works, can we be absolutely sure that it allows to obtain **all** clockable ordinals?

Comment: @lyricallywicked *"> First we set a variable equal to $\alpha$ (which we can do easily) < We cannot do this if we don't have a real number that encodes a limit ordinal $\alpha$."* This isn't quite correct. If some program $P$ starts from empty input and halts at $\alpha+1$ time, it isn't difficult at all to set up a variable (say $t$) whose value will mimic its running time (like ordinary progs.). Also, even when one clocks above $\omega_{CK}$ by recognizing codes of programs, it is easy to have a variable whose value will be exactly $\omega_{CK}$ (without ever forming its well-order first).

Comment: But as I mentioned above, while the above is trivial to set-up in extended models, I do not know how to set it up in a $\omega$ tape ITTMs (this is why I explicitly described in the answer that I was considering extended models). Anyway...

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "mimic its running time". Does it mean that an ITTM $m_1$ simulates another ITTM $m_2$ until $m_2$ halts? And how does it solve the problem? You still need full descriptions of all ordinals for all limit stages of the computation of $m_1$.

Comment: Note that we are using standard $\omega$ tape ITTMs.

Comment: @lyricallywicked I mentioned both in the main answer and in the edit that the construction being described was for extended models. For the model you are describing I suppose maybe someone else can answer. Generally speaking, if a question is about something specific, it is a good idea to make it explicit.

Comment: Having said that *I think*(but I am not fully sure) basically the way you might go in some $\omega$-tape model is take all pairs $(x,y) \in \mathbb{N}^2$ one at a time. The machines with indexes $x$ and $y$ and the machine $P$ (which halts at $\alpha$ from empty tape). You would simulate one step on each of them and continue this way. One of four possibilities will occur. (a) $x$ and $y$ both halt before $P$ does (b) $x$ halts before $P$ but $y$ doesn't (c) $y$ halts before $P$ but $x$ doesn't (d) $P$ halts before both $x$ and $y$. Possibilities (b),(c),(d) will essentially be rejected.

Comment: Based on possibility (a), one can carefully construct the required well-order relation I think (again I am not fully sure though). [Also this is just for construction in the "Edit" part of the answer. For the construction in main answer, I don't have a good idea]

Comment: I have a very important detail to clarify. If an ITTM $m_1$ clocks an arbitrary uncomputable ordinal, does there exist an ITTM $m_2$ that simulates $m_1$, but clocks a computable ordinal? If the answer is "Yes", it will open great possibilities. But if the answer is "An ordinal clockable by $m_2$ cannot be less than an ordinal clockable by $m_1$", then the problem remains unsolved.

Comment: @lyricallywicked *"If an ITTM $m_1$ clocks an arbitrary uncomputable ordinal, does there exist an ITTM $m_2$ that simulates $m_1$, but clocks a computable ordinal?"* The answer should definitely be "no". That much is true for sure.

Comment: @lyricallywicked I was thinking about this for past few days .... and it occurred to me that the construction I gave in "EDIT:" part of the answer doesn't quite always work. The main reason is due to gaps in clockable values. Basically for some clockable value $\alpha$, the construction will give a description for some $\beta \leq \alpha$. If $\alpha$ is "rare" enough, then I think it will give $\beta=\alpha$. The problem is that we will have to show separately then that the case $\beta=\alpha$ occurs for arbitrarily large values in supremum of clockable values. Sorry for the mistake in "EDIT"

Comment: Though the correction to it isn't that difficult actually. I would write it in the case only if you are interested (since my answer was already very long).

Comment: If the approach described in this answer allows to obtain _all_ clockable ordinals, then for _any_ ordinal $\alpha$, assuming that it is clockable, there must exist a _finite_ formula in a language similar to what is described in [one of my other questions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/320617/), so the question will be the following: is it possible to construct a formal language that allows to refer to specific real numbers that encode clockable ordinals? It seems that constructing such a language (that satisfies the basic property of _unambiguity_) is not easy...

Comment: @lyricallywicked Well the "constructible sets" seem to be closely related to what these programs can generate (and $\omega$ tape machines seem to be weaker than fully general models). But I don't really know anything whatsoever about constructibility (it is basically a set-theoretic topic though ...... you might check the link just below my answer). Furthermore I think you are also seeking an additional property on top of it (which I didn't fully understand).